# Is the PhoneApplicationPage visible during OnNavigatedTo event?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone clarify, is the page visible during the OnNavigatedTo event ? The documentation for it doesn't mention page visibility at all:

[MSDN OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

I see all the sample code updates the page (initial data loading, or re-loading state after tombstoning).

I want to make sure, as I don' want the user to see any flickering, or partial data as the page state is set.

**Update:** Ahh, I think it is hidden. If I add a delay of 10 seconds in to the OnNavigatedTo() call, then I don't see the page until after the 10 seconds:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // 10 seconds
```

When the app starts I see the splash screen for 10 seconds. When I get re-activated I see a black screen for 10 seconds then my updated page snaps in. Not definitive, but looks like it is hidden.

Comment: +1 good question. I believe it is not visible because the `Loaded` event hasn't occured yet.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good point about Loaded. I recall reading that the controls are added to the Visual Tree before Loaded event fires (Couldn't find that documented now though?). So I moved the 10 second timer in to Loaded() and clearly the page UI is displayed before Loaded() was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not already have loaded the visual tree, as usually this will happen before Loaded.

Do not that using Thread.Sleep isn't going to help verify this, since this blocks the primary UI thread of the app.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be correct. During NavigatedTo() the page is loaded but no visual tree yet. Then you get the page Loaded() event at which time the visual tree is now loaded and displayed.